# Is it possible to overload Generic parameters in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-types

I'm coming from C# and there you have functions parameters defined as a class.

```
Action        // void method
Action<T1>    // void method with a T1 parameter 
Action<T1,T2> // void method with a T1 and T2 parameter 
Func<T1>      // method that returns T1
Func<T1,T2>   // method with a T1 parameter, returning T2
```

etc

I understand this is opiniated but for me:

`function Koala(func1:Action, func2:Func<string,number>)`

is more readable then:

`function Koala(func1:()=>void, func1:(value1:string)=>number)`

on the backend we already use the first one. So our brains are already hardwired to it and it's easier to scan.

So the question is - is it possible to create something similar in TypeScript?

```
type Action = ()=>void;
type Action1<T1> = (a:T1)=>void;
type Action2<T1,T2> = (a:T1,b:T2)=>void;
type Action3<T1,T2,T3> = (a:T1,b:T2,c:T3)=>void;

type Func<T1> = ()=>T1;
type Func1<T1,T2> = (a:T1)=>T2;
type Func2<T1,T2,T3> = (a:T1,b:T2)=>T3;

var cheese:Func1<string,boolean>

let value = cheese('test');
```

This works of course. But I prefer to have the types overloaded instead of the 1,2,3 suffix, so Action<string,bool> automatically picks the right overload.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript does not have overloaded generic types.  There is an open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#39526](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39526) but so far they are not part of the language.

You can mostly simulate them with [default type arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) using a default that is unlikely for people to manually specify.  For example:

```
type Func<T1, T2 = Blank, T3 = Blank> =
  [T3] extends [Blank] ? (
    [T2] extends [Blank] ? () => T1 : (a: T1) => T2
  ) : (a: T1, b: T2) => T3
```

where you define `Blank` to be [the `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type) or possibly some nonce type like a unique symbol:

```
declare const __blank: unique symbol;
type Blank = typeof __blank
```

Essentially we use [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) to implement "overload resolution".  If `T2` and `T3` are both `Blank` then you use the one-arg type.  If just `T3` is `Blank` then you use the two-arg type.  And if `T3` isn't `Blank` then you use the three-arg type.

This behaves as you desired:

```
declare var cheese: Func<string, boolean>
// var cheese: (a: string) => boolean
let value = cheese('test');
```

---

I wouldn't really recommend trying this, though, unless your use case is so overwhelmingly compelling that it's worth adding complexity and possible fragility to your types.

For the particular examples shown, you can just use [rest tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-parameters-with-tuple-types) to represent functions of different arity in a single type:

```
type Func<A extends any[], R> = (...args: A) => R;
declare var cheese: Func<[string], boolean>
let value = cheese('test');

declare var bacon: Func<[string, number, Date, boolean], void>;
// var bacon: (args_0: string, args_1: number, args_2: Date, args_3: boolean) => void
```

Doing it this way works with the type system instead of against it.

The first version, fully written out (but not-recommended) is:

```
type Action0                = ()=>void;
type Action1<T1>            = (a:T1)=>void;
type Action2<T1,T2>         = (a:T1,b:T2)=>void;
type Action3<T1,T2,T3>      = (a:T1,b:T2,c:T3)=>void;
type Action4<T1,T2,T3,T4>   = (a:T1,b:T2,c:T3,d:T4)=>void;

type Func1<T1>          = ()=>T1;
type Func2<T1,T2>       = (a:T1)=>T2;
type Func3<T1,T2,T3>    = (a:T1,b:T2)=>T3;
type Func4<T1,T2,T3,T4> = (a:T1,b:T2,c:T3)=>T4;

declare type Action<T1=never,T2=never,T3=never,T4=never> = 
    [T1] extends [never] ?  Action0 : 
    [T2] extends [never] ?  Action1<T1> : 
    [T3] extends [never] ?  Action2<T1,T2> :
    [T4] extends [never] ?  Action3<T1,T2,T3> :
                            Action4<T1,T2,T3,T4>;
                        
declare type IFunc<T1,T2=never,T3=never,T4=never> = 
    [T2] extends [never] ?  Func1<T1> : 
    [T3] extends [never] ?  Func2<T1,T2> :
    [T4] extends [never] ?  Func3<T1,T2,T3> :
                            Func4<T1,T2,T3,T4>;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBRMBXANiALhA8gG4QBOmA9iACYRUDiEwpAlvACoCeM0SA3gLAAoIUiQ142EsnjlgUHEgD6igEbZgAawBcSdMGYBHdMigcwK8pgDcIpDi7IAQuo1IAvHYfkAZktUuhW3tuJAAxPXgAHjYARgAaJDYAJnckZxBNBLYAZlT0zQA+d1tRAG0cgF0kCAAPPGAqKCRS-I0qgH4kAAoS0Wbkqtr6xubWju6ASnci2KQdLpAdWKm3GaTeqfnFxPikFSWklZnswMFRcUlkQhASJHgACwhoCB1w4Cj5EmZgAHMEi0sEAyBVsAHpQUhrrcHk8oC9uttPt8fkc9uRARlbJgIAprphjKkYc8ugByPDyEkTGzCGkAX1OoEgsAQyAAqnCAErQHBsdAwbF8U6iYLIN5RACC1TqjBGGQ4pQqCQ5RQ8XQAdBqbj8oDpxaiOdTzhAJDcrjc7o9nq8IpFSkjfoq0RjgCCzkhsbiQPjkB4iXDSeScJTqbYLqbIeaVAhZNb3rb7X8kMB0OZSAkACK4CD-dHYjKOwjkZhUAqGpDgiO3KMyYBbEjaxQABh0CYSWqgihiOmTqZIbfrHaSOkzeH7DeyOgBeeAqMLxdOtKAA)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this extended answer! I learned a lot about TypeScript again. 

To be honest I am not completely appalled yet. This would be something I would define once in one of my core internal libraries with a piece of explanation (this just works like C#) and that would be it.

It feels very difficult to read, but if it's working it shouldn't create a lot of problems upstream right?

This feels like write once, never touch again. Similar to Regex 

Comment: I might try it out in my code. I'm not writing any external library code and If I'm hitting too many problems with this pattern it feels really easy to replace with your second answer or with the number suffix in my original question.

Comment: Hi @jcalz - my brain is a little bit differently wired and trying to figure out your answer I changed the code a bit so I can digest it more easily with my "C# brains".

The 'never' concept also seems to work really well, but do you think I am missing something that will make this fragile?

Comment: You can tweak the solution of course, but I'm not sure why you'd do so *in the question*, since it belongs in the answer if it belongs anywhere.  The fragility is potential: you're more likely to hit weird edge cases with conditional types than you are with rest tuples.  You can use `never` as long as you don't want to use `never` as a real type argument.  But if it works for your use cases then that's great.

Comment: sorry I am not familair with how this works on SO - should I edit your answer and add it to the bottom? or add my own answer? that feels a bit weird as it "steals" from your answer. Let me know and I'll add it to the right spot!

Comment: You could edit my answer and add it there if you think it's appropriate.  Adding a separate answer would be fine if it were a fundamentally different answer, but this seems like a tweak to mine so it belongs there.

Comment: I added the written out version to your answer. Not sure if it's your writing style so it feels a bit weird, but feel free to correct it.

Thanks for all your time.